# Using Project Tango Unity example projects

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I have tried to use the Project Tango unity examples found here; https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity with no success.

I have never used Unity before, and have successfully completed the Codelab: Motion Tracking example fromt he developer resources: https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-codelab-motion-tracking.

I downloaded the example files mentioned at the top, open one of the projects (tried several, all have the same problem). Once the project is open, I open the scene that come with it, I go to Build Settings, change platform to Android, change the Bundle Identifier and set the Minimum API Level to Jelly Bean 17 and finally click "Build and Run".

Now it starts to build the project, everything goes fine and the Unity logo shows up on the Tango. And that's it, the Unity logo shows up, no error messages on the computer, but nothing more happens. The program stalls at the Unity logo.

Am I missing some crucial step to get the example projects to actually run?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example code](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity) is Unity 5 based project, so please use the 5.x version of Unity to open it. If you use Unity 4.x version, the scene won't be opened up properly.

However, the code lab is based on Unity 4.6 and it is independent from our sample code. I understand this is a little bit confusing now, we are working on make sure the version are unified.

In short, I would suggest you open our example code with Unity 5.x version. You will be able to run it without a problem.

Comment: The joys of an increasing code base under active development - a train of ducklings constantly drifting out of phase -   Unity5 is the answer!

Comment: Oh wow, I first installed Unity 5, then I reverted to Unity 4.6 while doing the codelab (I don't remember exactly what prompted me to do the change, but something did), I'll return to Unity 5 and see how that works. I sadly won't be able to confirm this untill Tuesday, so the question will have to remain unresolved untill then.

Comment: @Morridini really sorry about the confusions.. We will update the code lab to Unity 5 soon. Also, try not to use Unity 5.0.0 version, I found that version cannot open the scene built in higher version..

Answer (score 1):

It was blank empty scene build. thats why after the unity logo it didn't load any scene or do anything.

You need to go to Unity Build Setting and drag and drop all the scenes from the examples folder in it.

Once you have all the scenes. Make sure that AreaDescriptionManagement is on the top of the list.

That is the only step missing from you.
Now, build and run. Everything should be fine.

[image: ScreenShot of Build Setting]